# How can I add an onmouseover tooltip pop-up to a PictureMarkerSymbol in JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When the mouse pointer hovers over a PictureMarkerSymbol, I need a tooltip to pop-up, then disappear onmouseout.

If that's not possible, then how might I have the marker's esri.symbol.TextSymbol show on mouseover and hide on mouseout?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the onMouseOver event of the layer that contains your picuture marker symbol:

API Docs:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#GraphicsLayer/onMouseOver

Examples from ESRI:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/fl_hover

These should get you started.

Comment: updated link for the mouse over: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer.html#event-mouse-over

Comment: @Jamie, What if you had had an ArcGis dynamic layer ? In that case the data is retrieved as a single image. How could the mouse over event be implemented then ?